# Understanding Shared member in vb.net in the context explained below

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a wrapper class for accessing sql server data in **vb.net** from this link
[ADO.NET Data Access Component for SQL Server in C# and VB.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20326/ADO-NET-Data-Access-Component-for-SQL-Server-in-Cs?msg=2226241#xx2226241xx)

Now in this link if we see the vb.net class two class level variable(SqlComm & SqlDA ) are declared as

```
Public Class VBDataAccess(Of TConnection As IConnection) 
Shared SqlComm As SqlCommand = Nothing 
Shared SqlDA As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing
```

and these are used in shared method of the class as follows

```
Public Shared Function NonQuery(ByVal CommandText As String, _
       ByVal ParameterValues As List(Of SqlParameter), _
       ByVal CommandType As CommandType) As Integer
    
    Dim res As Integer = 0
    Dim SqlConn As SqlConnection = Connection
    SqlConn.Open()
    
    Try
        SqlComm = New SqlCommand(CommandText, SqlConn)
        SqlComm.CommandTimeout = 600
        SqlComm.CommandType = CommandType
        If (ParameterValues IsNot Nothing) Then
            For Each Parameter In ParameterValues
                SqlComm.Parameters.Add(Parameter)
            Next
        End If
        res = SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return res
End Function
```

How this **SqlComm** will behave in case of multiple users accessing the function at same time. Is it going to create any problem ?

Comment: I would not use that code. The SqlCommand object implements IDisposable, and it's not being disposed by being a Static member of the class.

Comment: @Craig But SqlComm is declared at class level as shared not inside the function

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed that, so I have deleted my previous comment.  You are correct that there is a potentially serious issue if it is possible for multiple users to run through the function at the same time.  The first could try to run the query on a partially-set-up `SqlComm` (and which would be partially set up for the wrong query).

Comment: Yes, I too thought that it is going to be problematic but, the author of this class in shared link in the question is saying that it wont have any problem and this class is in use by so many applications with multiple users. I don't know how to confirm the actual outcome so posted the question here

Comment: +1 to what Hardcode has said. That aside though, based on the usage you've shown, there is absolutely not reason I can see for declaring SqlComm and SqlDA as class level shared fields